# setTimeout in for-loop prints unexpected garbage value for the first time when run in console window

Tags: javascript

```js
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
      setTimeout( function timer(){
        console.log( i );
      }, i*1000 );
    }
```

The above works in this snippet, but when ran in the **console window** I get unexpected results. The first value is garbage. What is the reason behind the first garbage value that gets printed?

[image]

Comment: It just prints 6, 5 times, as expected, since you didnt closure i.

Comment: What is that first value ?

Comment: @Shilly – It is `let`, not `var`

Comment: Every time its gives a random value @Rayon

Comment: It gave me `1..2..3..4..5` and that is what expected value is...

Comment: @Shilly I have already used let for block scoping for each iteration

Comment: What is this "garbage value"?

Comment: Run the snippet, it works fine. Not clear what your issue is

Comment: Getting a random value printed for first time @Liam

Comment: Must be some other code then because that works fine as far as I can see

Comment: I'm also getting values 1 to 5 printed. No idea what the 'Garbage Value' is.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh – That is the value returned by `setTimeout`...

Comment: Try running this snippet in your console window @Liam

Comment: @AbhimanyuSingh – You must specify that you are executing this code in `console`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value being printed in `console` is returned value of [**`setTimeout`([`timeoutID`])**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Syntax)

As you are executing your code in `console`, first value is always `returned` value of `expression`

In your case, for loop is being iterated `5` times, returned value is always incremented by `5` hence values will be `5..10..15` and so on. Latest value of `setTimeout` is returned.

One must have observed `undefined` being printed while executing code in `DevTools Console`, it is because of executing `void-function`, if `expression` returns a value, it is printed.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this behaviour lets change the code into:

```
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {() => 'a'}
```

This will log you:

> function () => 'a';

This means: The first strange result you see, **it's the return value from setTimeout function**.

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout function returns an integer id which can be used later for cancel the timer.The first number is the id that setTimeout function is returning.

You can run this function clearTimeout(id) to cancel the timer.